# Can I disable the join type select in the advanced filter builder in AgGrid?

Tags: ag-grid

I implemented AgGrid with React and Typescript. I'm using the Server Side Row Model. Is there a way to disable the join type select forcing to only use the AND type in the advanced filters builder?

I should use the builder UI as a product requirement, but the BE is not ready to manage both AND / OR join types yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.